# Generating a vector of dummy variables

Tags: linear-algebra, symbols

So I'm the situation of needing  analytical solutions to a family of equations of the form Ax=b, where A is an nxn matrix. I've written a function that does what I want, but I'm currently using a bit of a hack to generate arbitrary (dummy) variable names for the n-vector 'x' :

```
Map[Clear, Table["x" <> ToString[j], {j, n}]];
x = ToExpression[Table["x" <> ToString[j], {j, n}]];
```

Can anyone suggest a more elegant way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: Look at `Symbol` and `Unique`.  Also consider indexed variables, e.g. `x[1]`, `x[2]`, etc.

Comment: Consider also the use of the built-in `C` and `K` if you're going the "indexed variables" route.

Comment: @J.M. That was a very useful comment! I've never heard of `NHoldAll` before. Using `K` doesn't seem to have any advantages though, right?

Comment: Definately `Array` with some formal symbol or not formal if you are sure there's nothing defined on it. `m~Array~{5, 5}  . a~Array~5 // MatrixForm`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have several possibilities for this. The probably two easiest methods are first to use `Unique`

```
ClearAll[x];
x = Table[Unique["x"], {10}]
(* {x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16} *)
```

The good thing is, that when some of your variables `xn` are already defined, `Unique` will not return them. It always gives you fresh, unused symbols.

The other thing you should consider is, that `x[1]` can be used like a symbol too, although it isn't one. Therefore

```
ClearAll[x];
vars = Table[x[i], {i, 10}]
(* Out[15]= {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10]} *)
```

Can be used as valid variables too. In any case you should watch out that your variables are not assigned to values accidently. This is a common source of errors if you use them in combination with `Solve` or its friends.

**Why did I use `x=` in the first example and `vars=` in the second one?**

Let's take a very simple example

```
a = b[1];
OwnValues[a]
(*
  {HoldPattern[a] :> b[1]}
*)
```

and now we assume that the `b` would be an `a`, than we would get an `OwnValue`-rule like

```
HoldPattern[a] :> a[1]
```

Therefore, the moment you use `a` an substitution process starts which is only stopped by the `$RecursionLimit`, because `a` is evaluated into `a[1]` which again contains an `a` in the front. This is repeatedly replaced.

Therefore, if you want to use the second approach, **don't** call it like `x = Table[x[i], {i, 10}]`.

Comment: Evaluate x={x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5]}. In MMA 8.0.4 it exceeds the recursion limit. A bug? Whatever, it makes indexed variables a problem if used in the way the OP wants to use them.

Comment: @m_goldberg No, no bug, it is the expected behavior. I added an explanation and made clear how to use it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Mr.Wizard might prefer `vars = Array[x, 10]` :)

Comment: @halirutan. Thanks for the explanation. I understand what's going on with expressions like x = x[1] now. Another case of: don't think procedural; think rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that will do what you asked when it is passed a symbol and the length of the vector. The function returns the list of symbols it constructs; it assures that all the symbols in the list are clear of values.

```
SetAttributes[varVect, HoldFirst]

varVect[v_Symbol, n_Integer /; n > 0] := 
  Module[{vs = SymbolName[Unevaluated[v]], vars},
    vars = (vs <> ToString[#1]) & /@ Range[n];
    Clear @@ vars;
    Symbol /@ vars]

x = x2 = 1; x = varVect[x, 5]; x // FullForm => List[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]
x[[2]] // FullForm => x2
```

Comment: Certainly not the best way to proceed most of the time, but a direct answer to the question. +1

Comment: In place of `SymbolName[Unevaluated[v]]` I believe you can use `MakeBoxes[v]`.