# Simplifying results of a vector function to be nested (SECOND UPDATE)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, pattern-matching, symbolic, vector

(Oddly enough, the title for [another question that ended up dealing with an unrelated problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91151/how-does-one-define-a-function-that-takes-vectors-as-arguments-but-also-derivati) could have worked better here, but I didn't want to plagiarize.)

Given a symbolic vector function `U[t]` with independent variable `t` in an arbitrary number of dimensions, let `f[U[t]]:=Normalize[U'[t]]`. Then, one can succinctly define the unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors as `{T[t],N[t],B[t]}=NestList[f,U[t],3][[2;;]]`. (Note that in this case, `N` does *not* refer to the built-in numerical approximation function; it's just an unfortunate coincidence in notation.) Although there's no reason why `NestList` has to stop at three layers, I have been having problems with going beyond such due to the size and complexity of the output, which I know can be greatly simplified. Here are the methods I have come up with so far, and the problems I have encountered with each of them:

- Using the given definition: This leads to instances of `Norm'[_]`, which prevents much of the simplification.
- Adjusting the given definition: Changing the definition of `f` to something like `f[v_]:=#/Sqrt[#.#]&[Dt[v,t]]` gets closer, but `Dot` is neither distributive over `Plus` nor commutative, as Mathematica includes the possibility of the arguments to `Dot` being rectangular matrices, which would indeed produce different results.
- Using `Simplify` and the like: This takes a rather long time, given that the input expression is a 16-level fraction with square roots.
- Using assumptions to indicate vectors: `Assuming[VectorQ[v],_]` fails because lone variables that aren't explicitly lists are treated as scalars, making `VectorQ[v]` evaluate to `False`.
- Using patterns to indicate vectors: While using expressions like `{u__}` is an intriguing possibility, when taking the derivative, Mathematica ends up producing the nonsensical expression `Derivative[1,0][Pattern][u,__]` as a part of the result.
- Adding the distributive-over-`Plus` and commutative properties to the dot product: While the latter is easy enough to do via the `Orderless` attribute, I have no idea how to do the former, given the aforementioned problems with `VectorQ`. (For the record, I'm talking about `a.(b+c)==a.b+a.c`.)
- Defining a substitute for the `Dot` function with those properties: While the substitute function itself does not have to be defined, defining its properties would likely require reverse-engineering of the `Dot` function, and especially how it interacts with the `Dt` function, which might or might not be against the terms of the license, depending on whether the reverse-engineering or it being common mathematical knowledge takes precedence within the context of the license.
- Defining a substitute for the `Dt` function: This runs into the problem with attributes.
- Doing everything manually: While I am better able to find repeating sub-patterns within the expressions myself than I am programming Mathematica to do it, the computer is far faster than me, and I'm sure I'll make a sign error or something somewhere.

Is there any way to fix any of these?

---

**FIRST UPDATE:** I ended up using a substitute `Dot` function and defining its attributes (aside from `Orderless`) through assignments (e.g. `dot[a_,b_+c_]:=dot[a,b]+dot[a,c]`). However, factoring expressions out over `Times` had been an issue, as incorrectly factoring out undotted instances of `Derivative[_][U][t]` would lead to the nonsensical result of a dot product between a scalar and a vector, or even between two scalars. Nevertheless, I found a possible way around this by adding a function `i` that encloses undotted instances of `Derivative[_][U][t]` as a sort of indicator, and serves as an identity function otherwise; it would finally disappear using the assignment of `dot[i[a_],i[b_]]:=dot[a,b]`. (In other words, one could use `MatchQ[i]` or `FreeQ[i]` on an expression as a substitute for the [non-functioning] `VectorQ[expr]`.)

But now I've run into another issue that, on its face, seems bizarre. Consider the expression `dot[2*i[U''[t]]*dot[U'[t],U'[t]],-2*i[U'[t]]*dot[U'[t],U''[t]]]`, an actual subexpression encountered for the unit normal vector. The assignment `dot[a_,b_*c_?FreeQ[i]]:=c*dot[a,b]` fails to do anything, due to `MatchQ[-2*i[U'[t]]*dot[U'[t],U''[t]],b_*c_?FreeQ[i]]` returning `False` (even if the test `?MemberQ[i]` is added onto `b_` in addition to or instead of the test on `c_`, and/or the positions of `b_` and `c_` are swapped with each other), despite the fact that all of the following return `True`:

- `MatchQ[-2*i[U'[t]]*dot[U'[t],U''[t]],b_*c_]`
- `MatchQ[-2*i[U'[t]]*dot[U'[t],U''[t]],b_*c_Integer]`
- `MatchQ[-2*i[U'[t]]*dot[U'[t],U''[t]],b_*c_?IntegerQ]`

Now what is going on here?

---

**SECOND UPDATE:** Immediately after posting the previous update, I found that setting the assignment `dot[a_,b_*c_/;FreeQ[c,i]]:=c*dot[a,b]` actually does work in solving the second issue (and the whole problem in general), but this only makes that issue even more strange: what would allow `FreeQ[dot[U'[t],U''[t]],i]` and `MatchQ[dot[U'[t],U''[t]],c_/;FreeQ[c,i]]` to evaluate to `True`, yet force `MatchQ[dot[U'[t],U''[t]],c_?FreeQ[i]]`, a supposedly identical expression, to evaluate to `False`?